# TextFieldParser replacement in .net Core 1

Tags: c#, asp.net-core-mvc

In the past, for c# .net MVC projects, I used TextFieldParser from the Visual Basic Reference.  Now with .Net Core 1 that no longer seems to be an option.  At least I can't figure out how to add the visual basic reference and I imagine if you did wouldn't it make it so it wasn't cross-platform?

The TextFieldParser was great because it covered all of my CSV import needs with great flexibility.

Is there a replacement for the TextFieldParser in .netCore that I am missing?  Or is there a way to use the current textfieldparser without breaking cross-platform compatibility?

Comment: Use Reflector or ILSpy to disassemble the TextFieldParser class.  Both products output C#, so you should be able to reconstruct it within your project.

Comment: @SamAxe Thanks for the tip.  I will give that a try as well.

Answer (score 5):

I have just tried [CsvHelper](http://joshclose.github.io/CsvHelper/) - a .NET library for [reading](http://joshclose.github.io/CsvHelper/reading) and [writing](http://joshclose.github.io/CsvHelper/writing) CSV files. It covers all needs. Looks fast, flexible and [easy to use](http://joshclose.github.io/CsvHelper/configuration). Supports reading and writing of [custom class objects](http://joshclose.github.io/CsvHelper/mapping). It works fine with `.NET Core` (as it supports `.NET Standard 2.0`) as well as with `.NET Framework 4.5` see dependencies on [NuGet page](https://www.nuget.org/packages/CsvHelper/).

Comment: This is fantastic!

Answer (score 4):

For those that need it, `TextFieldParser` can handle more than just CSV. It supports tab delimited, fixed width fields, etc.

I created a 1 to 1 port of `TextFieldParser` for .NET Core.

You can get it via nuget by searching for `TextFieldParserCore`.
https://www.nuget.org/packages/TextFieldParserCore/1.0.0

Comment: You are a life saver....really didnt want to have to upgrade from 2.0 to 3.....or change all my code to use a different parser

Answer (score 4):

.net core 3 added that support

Comment: Found it. Can be used after the include: `using Microsoft.VisualBasic.FileIO;`

Answer (score 0):

I have a .NET Standard 2.0 project that I can't upgrade and didn't want to add a large library or re-write methods.  I added TextFieldParserStandard from NuGet, which added no additional dependencies.  The only code modification was changing the namespace from Microsoft.VisualBasic.FileIO to TextFieldParserStandard.

Answer (score -1):

Parsing a CSV string or file is a fairly straightforward task. Loop through all the lines and `String.Split` them at the separator character. Whether or not you use a library to do this for you, that's up to you.

Here's a pretty flexibel TextReader extension method I came up with:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO;

namespace Extensions
{
    /// <summary>Extension method to parse any character separated string OR file.</summary>
    /// <param name="mapFunction">Expression to map data to the desired format</param>
    /// <param name="separator">The character delimiting columns</param>
    /// <param name="skipLines">Amount of heading lines to skip</param>
    public static class TextReaderExtensions
    {
        public static IEnumerable<T> ParseCsvData<T>(this TextReader reader, Func<string[], T> mapFunction, char separator = ',', short skipLines = 1)
        {
            IEnumerable<string[]> readCsvLines()
            {
                string line;
                while ((line = reader.ReadLine()) != null)
                {
                    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(line) && skipLines-- < 1)
                    {
                        yield return line.Split(separator);
                    }
                }
            }

            foreach (var csvLine in readCsvLines())
            {
                yield return mapFunction.Invoke(csvLine) ?? default;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Example usage from string input:

```
using (var textReader = new StringReader("Comma,Separated,Value,String"))
{
    var persons = textReader.ParseCsvData(columns => new Person
    {
        Id = columns[0],
        Name = columns[1],
        Age = columns[2]
    });

    return persons.ToList();
}
```

Example usage from file stream input:

```
using (var textReader = new StreamReader(fileStream))
{
    var formattedStrings = textReader.ParseCsvData(data => data[1] + " is " + data[2] + " years old.");
    return formattedStrings.ToList();
}
```

The possibilities are endless.

Do whatever you want...

POWER TO THE PEOPLE!!

Comment: Note this doesn't handle cases where there's a comma or new line in the value.

Comment: Update your code to parse csv records like this: `Comma,"Sepa\r\na,ted",Value,String\r\nNew,Line,Normal,Values`